# Send email to 100 recipients with 15 time interval with rails or some service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

How could i send email to a big number of the recipients with some time interval, for example 15 minutes between each email? I would be happy with any solution like special service which allows to do this, or with Rails code, for example with using Action Mailer.

Comment: You can do this by active jobs in rails using sidekiq.You can create background job to send email to big number of recipients and why do you need a time interval.?

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan task is that i couldn't send 100 email at one moment. Each user should get his email in some time period after previous. I know how to use active job and sidekiq but confusing how to set interval for background process

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to perform a background job.

[ActiveJob](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) can do that for you!

Look at this documentation, so your Rails application can send emails at the desired speed, while continuing your other processing.

You will be able to do for example :

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later(wait: 15.minutes)
```

Comment: As i understand this code just will give me 15 min pause between some action which will call this code and emails sending, but i need 15 min interval between each email. For example i have some action, on this action i send to ActiveJob object which contains 100 emails. In Active Job i iterate object to get each emails and send email to it. But each iteration/email sending should have 15 minutes time interval